# USB Modems Duplicate MAC Address

Tags: mac-address

I am having trouble with Huawei USB modems (E5576-856) that have same mac address when connected with USB. This creates mac collisions when connected on VPN due to mac duplication.

Both firmware update and Driver(RNDIS Based internet sharing Device) update did not solve the issue. Windows 10.

Edit:
The setup as follows:
Each laptop is connected to separate modems via USB. With this setup, the laptops creates virtual adapters with same mac-addresses and when they dial-in to the VPN they cause the mac-address collision, whereby other client gets disconnected when other connects.

Comment: Where do these mac-address collisions occur? The VPN server sees duplicates when 2 clients dial-in simultaneously using such a USB modem? Please edit you question to clarify this further. Please remember. We are not familiar with your exact setup. You will have to provide some more context. Else we just be guessing.

Comment: What operating system?  Windows 10 allows you to change the MAC address of a network device.

Comment: Check the modem's manual.  Many modems allow you to change their MAC

Comment: Ok, I see I can modify MAC address for the Modems, but for now I am running away from this route as I might create further collisions unless there are local mac-addressing like in IP addressing? Also if the user changes the Laptop/PC I might have to re-configure since the change is applied on the PC not the modem.